# Install docker-volume-netshare on Linux AMI

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, centos, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to install this [plugin](http://netshare.containx.io/docs/getting-started#nfs-prerequisites-on-linux) on my ECS optimized instance (Linux AMI) by following this [blog](https://medium.com/@eon01/easy-docker-orchestration-with-docker-1-12-aws-efs-and-the-swarm-mode-87d51b6d5ad2#.hx2kgrsxa) because I have a problem with mounting the EFS inside the docker instance.

In the plugin website, they said that we can install the package as follows:

```
wget https://github.com/ContainX/docker-volume-netshare/releases/download/v0.18/docker-volume-netshare_0.18_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i docker-volume-netshare_0.18_amd64.deb
```

When I do the same I get this error:

```
sudo: dpkg: command not found
```

I guess it's obvious as it's an `On Ubuntu / Debian installation`. Can't find any way to install it in my Linux AMI (`RHEL/CentOS`)

I also tried this:

```
$ go get github.com/ContainX/docker-volume-netshare
$ go build
```

Then I got this error:

```
can't load package: package .: no buildable Go source files in /home/ec2-user
```

Please help me.